# Can't migrate or connect to postgresql using laravel 8 with laragon

Tags: postgresql, laravel-8, laragon

I have the following error

```
C:\laragon\www\project>php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\laragon\www\covid-care\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕
     }
    682▕


  1   C:\laragon\www\covid-care\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\laragon\www\covid-care\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=tesdb;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "postgres", "postgres", [])
```

Already had pdo_pgsql and pgsql enabled
[laragon extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fbFW.png)

My pgsql database [pgsql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuOAl.png)

I don't really understand what went wrong.... how to solve this?